# tor quit unexpectedly and wont re-open (even after I restart)

Tags: mac

I get the message

"Tor unexpectedly exited. this may be due to a bug...."

I've re installed tor multiple times and nothing works

Comment: Can you get any kind of Tor log (Onion menu -> Network Settings -> Copy Tor Log to clipboard)?